# Get number of occurrences based on Index and Column in Pandas DataFrame to create different view of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Am trying to get the occurrences of certain pattern based on Index in Dataframe , any help would be appreciated

Have manually added a column as Index and need to get occurrences of pattern based on Index and the column

```py
dataset sample      
a(index)    d   
pattern 1   test    
pattern 1   test    
pattern 1   test2   
pattern 2   test3   
pattern 2   test    
pattern 2   test    

expected output     

Am looking to make a dataframe something like below with the above sample data

pattern  test test2 test3
----------------------------------
pattern 1   2   1        0
pattern 2   2   0        1
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['a','d']).count().reset_index(name='Count')`

Comment: If a is index, try df.groupby([df.index, 'd']).count().reset_index()

Comment: **Thanks for the quick update , have re-phased the question.. seems i did not express correctly. Any suggestion here would be helpful.

Am trying to understand % of certain pre-defined value based on pattern**

Answer (score 1):

If you reset the index, it's a pretty straightforward `groupby`:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
               d
a
pattern 1   test
pattern 1   test
pattern 1  test2
pattern 2  test3
pattern 2   test
pattern 2   test

In [19]: df.reset_index().groupby(['a', 'd']).apply(len).reset_index()
Out[19]:
           a      d  0
0  pattern 1   test  2
1  pattern 1  test2  1
2  pattern 2   test  2
3  pattern 2  test3  1
```

Comment: Have re-phrased the question , please have a look and let me know if this is feasible